# Como trabalhar com ramificações remotas?

Tags: git

Estou tendo dificuldades em trabalhar com uma ramificação remota do git:

Temos um servidor na nossa rede interna onde está o projeto. Dois programadores irão trabalhar e ele tem duas ramificações: **master** e **Devel**. Pretendemos manter a **master** praticamente intocada, sendo assim vamos desenvolver nossos trabalhos na **Devel**.

No servidor criei a ramificação **Devel**, e quando vou trabalhar com ela eu clono:

```
git clone //10.0.0.100/projeto --branch Devel
```

Na cópia local eu trabalho normalmente e executo os **commits** referentes ao que estou fazendo:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Teste de alterações"
```

No final do trabalho, eu envio para o servidor:

```
git push origin Devel
```

Porém, quando clono em outro local (ou outra máquina) a ramificação "Devel", não vem nenhuma das alterações.

Onde foi que eu errei?

Comment: Qual a mensagem na execução do comando push?
O remote está configurado corretamente? Verifique usando: git remote -v

Comment: Quando dou o comando recebo o retorno:
`origin  //MEUSERVIDOR/MEUPROJETO (fetch)
origin  //MEUSERVIDOR/MEUPROJETO (push)`

Comment: @egomesbrandao estou enviando o push sem nenhuma flag adicional só `git push origin Devel` mesmo, quando estou fazendo, estou recebendo o retorno `Everything up-to-date`

Comment: Basicamente o que eu quero é:
Manter duas ramificações em um servidor na minha rede interna (não precisa de senha para acesso nem nada), onde dois programadores trabalharão, quando forem trabalhar eles vão clonar o projeto localmente e quando terminarem de fazer a modificação vão enviar de volta para o servidor.
Estou quase conseguindo, só não sei porque (apesar da mensagem "up-to-date) quando eu clono, não vejo as modificações do último Push.

Comment: Eu quero saber se o remote está configurado (git remote -v) e se o up-stream está configurado (git branch --all), para saber se você está enviando as coisas para os lugares certos, pois parece que você está "commitando" em uma branch e que ele não está conectada com alguma remota.

Comment: @egomesbrandao ok... O retorno para o comando `git remote -v` é `origin  //10.0.0.100/projeto (fetch)` `origin  //10.0.0.100/projeto (push)` e o retorno para o comando `git branch --all` é `* Devel`  `master`  `remotes/origin/Devel` 
 `remotes/origin/master`. Posso confirmar com toda certeza que localmente estou commitando no branch certo, no bash do MINGW64 conta o Branch `(Devel)` no final. Agradeço antecipadamente a atenção.